# Bootstrap Hero unit with no background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can make a Bootstrap Hero unit with no background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.hero-unit{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); // use rgba and set Opacity to 0 for transparent.
 }
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7879/)

Comment: Hi bcdoding, thanks for you comment but I want a hero unit with absolutely no background color! what I want is just a container at the top but with hero unit capabilities

Comment: @BehrouzHosseiniK. I have updated the fiddle and my example to utilize no background (transparent).